# CurrentThread/ProcessThread objects

Tags: c#

In the .NET BCL, there is a CurrentThread and a ProcessThread object. What is the difference between these?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CurrentThread` static property on the `System.Threading.Thread` class is the current CLR `System.Threading.Thread` instance. The CLR Thread is an abstraction over the underlying win32 thread. The `System.Diagnostics.ProcessThread` class gives one access to the win32 threads, largely for perfomance tracking.

A key distinction of CLR threads is that they are not fixed to win32 threads.

Comment: Just to add more inputs for the point that CLR thread creates a layer of abstraction over windows threads. This layer of abstraction creates some limitations like u can't assign idle and time-critical thread priority to a CLR thread when it actually exists for a windows thread. CLR has reserved those thread priorities for some threads that it runs on its own for e.g. finalizer thread of garbage collector runs on time-critical priority.

Comment: I didn't get the last point that CLR threads is not fixed to win32 threads. Do you mean that there are other possible types of threads (other than win32 type of thread) to which a CLR thread can point to or u r talking about cardinality relationship between a CLR thread and a windows thread. AFAIK there is one to one mapping between CLR thread and windows thread. Whenever you new up the thread class in C#, behind the scenes it ultimately creates a windows thread only. Two CLR threads can NEVER point to same win32 thread.

Answer (score 14):

It is a hangover from a SQL Server project when .NET 2.0 was being designed.  They pressed the CLR team *really* hard to break the link between the .NET Thread class and an operating system thread.  They had reason to at the time, SQL Server supports "light-weight" threads that are implemented as fibers.  A fiber is the Windows implementation of a "co-routine", something that was popular about 15 years ago.

The project was a bust, they couldn't get it reliable enough.  Sadly, we are stuck with *no* easy way to map a Thread to a ProcessThread.  Quite a loss.  Maybe somebody, some day, will take advantage of the uncoupling, I haven't seen it done yet.

The only possible mapping you've got available now is to P/Invoke GetCurrentThreadId() inside the thread itself.  That returns a TID that you can match to a ProcessThread.Id.

Comment: What about `AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId()`? Any chance that it will ever be *undeprecated*?