# Difference between Thread class and ProcessThread class in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I am learning Threading and I am bit confused, what the real difference between the [ProcessThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthread.aspx) Class and the [Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx) class, I mean in which scenario to use which one and why ?

Any articles will be helpfull !

Comment: What is the documentation do you find confusing?

Comment: similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946111/currentthread-processthread-objects

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ProcessThread is rather a Thread **Info** class on threads of a process. You cannot start, stop or abort it, it just some information on the thread.

Thread class on the other hand is the one that is used (or rather was used before TPL) for multi-threading applications.

Comment: And that is why even C# language writers have chosen different namespaces for them. ProcessThread class resides in System.Diagnostics (for debugging and informational purposes) namespace while Thread class resides in System.Threading (for real multi-threading work) namespace. ProcessThread class gives you more vital information about the underlying windows thread over which .net framework simply creates an abstraction for use under the purview of CLR.

Comment: I understand that `System.Threading.Thread` is different from `System.Diagnostics.ProcessThread`, but I'm looking for a link between both (when I have a `System.Diagnostics.ProcessThread`, how can I know which `System.Threading.Thread` it corresponds to?

Answer (score 3):

The ProcessThread describes an operating system (OS) thread where as the Thread class describes a .Net framework thread. At present .Net Threads are implemented using OS Threads but they may not be in future releases of .Net or on frameworks on other platforms.

You will often find that your applications contain more threads than the ones you have created and these extra threads are often not .Net threads.

Answer (score 1):

ProcessThread class is used for obtaining information about a thread that is currently running on the system. There is no direct difference between them both are different.